# I got an error when I tried to create a browser in python

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, pyqt5

I was trying to create a browser using PyQt5 in python. This is my code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.showMaximized()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('browser')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

When I tried to run this code I got the following error.

```
This application failed to start because no Qt Platform plugin
could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

[image]

I checked over the internet and I even updated my bios, it didn't fix.

I use python 3.9. I got this error when I used this code in Pycharm community edition 2020.3 in Windows

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Judging by the look of the error message I would assume Windows.

Comment: @EliaTolin there is no plugins folder inside Qt folder(11th step), and there is no bin folder inside Qt folder(16th step).

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Open File Explorer
2. Click This PC or Computer
3. Open C Drive
4. Search pyqt5_tools
5. Wait For Search To Complete
6. Click pyqt5_tools
7. Right-Click on pyqt5_tools
8. Click Open Folder Location
9. Open PyQt5 Folder
10. Open Qt Folder
11. Open plugins Folder
12. Copy platforms Folder
13. Click site-packages
14. Open pyqt5_tools Folder
15. Open Qt Folder
16. Open bin Folder
17. Paste The Folder

Good Luck and Good Code!